# Button open new window

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-7

I have a button and i want open URL toPainel in a new window/tab.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button" :onclick="toPainel.concat(painel.id,'\'',';')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Painel" target="_blank"> button </button>

data() {return {toPainel:"window.location='http://localhost:8000/painel?id="}};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<button type="button" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');">google</button>
```

Comment: is not what i need. ;/